# Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, quoting

I have a lot of .txt files that I want to add the name of it on the first line.

I had this command:

```sh
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/^/$ARGV\n/' `find . -name '*.txt'`
```

This works perfectly in Linux but, in Windows, I get:

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Comment: The Windows command shell uses double-quotes for quoting, not single quotes. But that's not the end of it. It doesn't have backticks exactly. (It can be done via `for`.) And then there's the fact that you probably don't have `find` installed. (Well, Windows comes with a program called `find`, but it's a completely different program.) The finding can be done using `for`

Comment: Tip: The command line option `-0777` does the same as `BEGIN{undef $/;}`.

Comment: Maybe use [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)?

Comment: In Linux `perl -0777 -i'.bak' -pe 's/^/Filename: $ARGV\n-------------------------\n/' *.txt`, in Windows `perl -0777 -i".bak" -pe "s/^/Filename: $ARGV\n-------------------------\n/" *.txt`.

Comment: @PolarBear `*.txt` is not recursive, as find is. A Perl solution must rely on File::Find, or equivalent. Also, you don't need quotes with `-i`, `-i.bak` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following script would work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
sub wanted {
    if (m/\.txt\z/) {
        system "perl", "-i.bak", "-0777", "-pe", 's/^/$ARGV\n/', $File::Find::name;
    }
}
find(\&wanted, ".");
```

This script uses File::Find as suggested in the comments on the question. `find` takes a callback and a list of directories to search. The callback, named `wanted`, checks if the filename ends in ".txt". If it does, the script spawns a new perl interpreter editing the file in place inserting the filename before the first line.

There's probably a way to do it without using `system`.